# How to efficiently group multiple rows in a csv-file with python

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple csv files containing item and invoicing data (proprietary and edifact files).
They look roughly like this:

```
0001;12345;Item1
0002;12345;EUR;1.99
0003;12345;EUR;1.99
```

The always start with 0001 but do not necessarily have more than one row.
How do I group them efficiently?

Currently I read them line by line, split them by ';', and add them all to one list until the first value is again 0001.

Should I first split them using regular expressions and then continue parsing? What is the most pythonic way?

Comment: Before knowing if efficiency is needed you might want to evaluate the performance of your current solution; did you try it? What performance do you have and is it an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my knowledge of EDIFACT-style files, they're basically hierarchical, with some row code (`0001` here) acting as a "start-of-group" symbol.

So yeah – something like this is a fast, Pythonic way to group by that symbol. (`input_file` can just as well be a disk file, but for the sake of a self-contained example, it's an `io.StringIO()`.)

This particular implementation has the extra feature of crashing if the file smells invalid, i.e. doesn't start with an `0001` record.

```py
import io
from pprint import pprint
import csv

input_file = io.StringIO("""
0001;12345;Item1
0002;12345;EUR;1.99
0003;12345;EUR;1.99
0001;12345;Item2
0002;12345;EUR;1.99
0003;12345;EUR;1.99
0001;12345;Item3
0002;12345;EUR;1.99
0003;12345;EUR;1.99
0001;12345;Item4
0002;12345;EUR;1.99
0003;12345;EUR;1.99
""".strip())


groups = []
for line in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=";"):
    if line[0] == "0001":
        groups.append([])
    groups[-1].append(line)

pprint(groups)
```

The output is a list of lists of split rows:

```
[[['0001', '12345', 'Item1'],
  ['0002', '12345', 'EUR', '1.99'],
  ['0003', '12345', 'EUR', '1.99']],
 [['0001', '12345', 'Item2'],
  ['0002', '12345', 'EUR', '1.99'],
  ['0003', '12345', 'EUR', '1.99']],
 [['0001', '12345', 'Item3'],
  ['0002', '12345', 'EUR', '1.99'],
  ['0003', '12345', 'EUR', '1.99']],
 [['0001', '12345', 'Item4'],
  ['0002', '12345', 'EUR', '1.99'],
  ['0003', '12345', 'EUR', '1.99']]]
```

Answer (score -1):

If the files have the same columns, it would be interesting to read it in dataframes, and append to each one this thing.
`df1= pd.read_csv(Path+File1, sep=';') 
 df2= pd.read_csv(Path+File2, sep=';') 
 df2.append(df1, ignore_index = True, sort=False).`

Afterward, you can just sort by the first column that contains the '0001'

`df.sort_values(by=['col1'], ascending=False)`